# Is it possible to do user authentication without DB or PHP?

Tags: html, css, authentication

I am trying to find a solution through which I could implement user authentication (login / password) within HTML5 and without using any server language or database.

Is it even possible or I am just being crazy?

Thanks.

Comment: you can generate static content which can be decoded only using passwords/keys but it is not auth, it is crypt.

Comment: hahah! Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Guys, what if I then use PHP and not a Database. What are my options then? Filling may be?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to store every user's login and password in a database and use PHP to access it.  This is assuming you're storing many users' information and if one wants to login it matches the entered password/login with the onea in the database when they created an account.

Comment: What if I use PHP and then use filing system?

Comment: Well you're going to have to deal with some kind of database, so you decide.